# C++ switch statement count output

Tags: c++, for-loop, switch-statement

I am having trouble forming the output statement for this program.  The correct output should print the same input number that its numerical value holds. .

Comment: This look very much like a "Intro to programming" assignment. And the code you provided, unfortunately, has little resemblance to what you're trying to write.

Comment: I don't see a question anywhere. What is it you need help with?

Comment: What exactly is this code supposed to do?

Comment: "The correct output should print the same input number that its numerical value holds." Wait, what? I don't really understand what you want to do here.

Comment: It seems like it's trying to construct a number digit-by-digit, right?

Comment: I think he means if you input '1' 3 times and '2' 4 times (as something like "2 2 1 2 2 1 1", the output would be "1 1 1 2 2 2 2", you print out the count of the digit using that particular digit.  Confusing!

Comment: I think what he means is to input three numbers, then output those exact same numbers, using loops.

Comment: @jonsca: Unfortunately, your interpretation doesn't jive with his example.

Comment: @Emile It does.  He has entered the number one 3 times.  To indicate that, he has printed a "bar chart" using 1 as the label.  That's why I was indicating that the pattern didn't matter.  Otherwise, he wouldn't need to keep the counts, just echo the input.

Answer (score 1):

You definitely need to move the `switch` statement within the while loop (Edit: this was based on the OP's initial posting of the code).

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you want something similar to this:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int standard, count1, count2, count3, count4, count5;

    // Initialize your int's
    standard = count1 = count2 = count3 = count4 = count5 = 0;

    do {
        cout<< "Enter value: ";
        cin >> standard;

        // Switch through your cases
        switch(standard)
        {
        case 1:
            count1++;
        break;
        case 2:
            count2++;
        break;
        case 3:
            count3++;
        break;
        case 4:
            count4++;
        break;
        case 5:
            count5++;
        break;
        }
    } while(standard != 0);

    // Do this type of loop for all your count vars
    for(int i=0;i<count1;++i)
        cout<< "1";

    for(int i=0;i<count2;++i)
        cout<< "2";

    // And so on...

    return 0;
}
```

For the for loops, note that you are going from 0 to `<` the total number. If you went to `<=` you would go passed that number. The range `[0,4]` = 5 (or in our case `[0,5)` for the set of integers) and so does `[1,5]` so remember to mind your offsets. Good luck!

**EDIT:** Also recognize that the position of the `switch` statement has been moved. By placing it in the loop, you actually count every time it runs through the loop. For instance, the loop "blocks" (in other words, it waits for input) at your `cin` line. When it receives an input (though you have no error-checking, so a non-int value may cause a segfault), it will then check it against the switch statement and increment accordingly.

By placing the `switch` statement outside the loop (as you initially had it), please realize that nothing happens. You have no `default` condition in your `switch` statement, nor a case for handling `0`. If you check your `switch` after the loop, `standard == 0` since that is how you exited the loop in the first place (therefore, standard's last value will be retained).

Furthermore, revisit the for loop syntax. This can be done in several ways, there are many good articles here on SO which can help you further by using the search function, but it basically works like this:

```
for(STARTING_POINT;SOME_CONDITION;SOME_CHANGE);
```

STARTING_POINT = The value where you should start your loop
SOME_CONDITION = When this condition is true, then the loop will terminate
SOME_CHANGE    = how to change your variable (i.e. from starting point) until it reaches the condition

So a loop which looks like this:

```
for(int i=1;i<=5;++i){ ... }
```

means to initialize `int i` to value `1`
Until `i <= 5` run through your loop
Then, on every iteration, increment `i` by one (which is `++i` or `i++`)

Finally, as you can see, I added an initialization line to my int's. What this does is it gives your variables some starting value rather than garbage value.

I hope this helps

Regards,
Dennis M.

Comment: -1 for lots of code and little explanation.

Comment: @Potatoswatter: There is not much else to explain. I explained the ranges on the for loop which is where he was having the most issues it seemed to me. Looking at his original code, perhaps I can disect the for loop further, but that's all there is. This is basically the "Hello World" of loops (disregarding I/O, but this is, again, very basic since he seemingly understands it). He is not overloading the `++` operator so it is still increment as well. Please elaborate if you would like to see further explanation on this code.

Comment: You fundamentally changed the functionality and said "it looks like this is what you want." Clearly he's still at the "Hello, world" level and he won't be helped by having homework done for him. Even if it seems very basic to us, that is the level of instruction he needs.

Comment: @Potatoswatter: I will add some more comments, however, if this was marked homework I would not have provided such code - the only thing that has been changed was the position of the `switch` statement which I will append to my response.

Comment: The `homework` tag is almost always added by answerers, not askers, so you can't rely on it. Besides the position of the `switch`, you rewrote the loop that produces the output, and made a number of stylistic changes.

Answer (score 0):

I really don't understand what you're trying to accomplish, but this part here:

```
  for (count1=0; count1<=5; count1++)
        cout << "1";
```

Is going to print out '1' 6 times in a row, regardless of the input. Could you explain a bit more what you're trying to do?

Comment: This isn't an answer; it should have been posted as a comment to the original question. You might want to remove it before you start collecting down votes.

Comment: @Ken: most of the time I'd agree, but given how vague the "question" is here, I'd be quite happy in guessing that what Rob's pointed out is part of the problem the OP is trying to solve.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my interpretation: You want to input a sequence of numbers (ending with zero), then output those exact same numbers, using loops.

Here's some pseudocode to give you a hint.

```
Declare an array of int's large enough to hold all your input numbers.
Declare a counter c = 0.

Begin loop while input is not 0
    Input number from user and store it in array[c].
    Increment counter c.
End loop

Begin loop i from 0 to c-1
    Output number that is in array[i].
End loop
```

No need to use a switch statement and a counter for each possible number. Just store each input in it's own spot in an array.